# Animation.css classes not working

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I am using animation.css and jquery to create a slideInleft animation so that content comes in and stays and then slideOutleft and then I want content to come in from right I mean slideInright and stay for few secs and then slideOutRIght. This effect should happen continuously. I am trying this but something is wrong . To start off with the left animation I have written code like this

```
var txt = Data;
    function AnimateOneByOne()
    {   
        if( xCnt < txt.length && txt[xCnt].value){
        $("#value").empty().append(txt[xCnt].value.toFixed(2)+" "+txt[xCnt].units).addClass('slideInLeft',

          function(){ AnimateOneByOne() });
        $("#text").empty().append(txt[xCnt].name).addClass('slideInLeft',

          function(){ AnimateOneByOne() });
        }
        xCnt += 1; 
    }

    AnimateOneByOne();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have on the element you want to animate both the animation general class: "animated" the class of specific animation, like: "slideInLeft".
So in the end it will look like this:

```
'<div class="animated slideInLeft">I am animated</div>
```

You can do this easily with "addClass", if you already using jQuery.

```
 $(this).addClass('animated ' + animationName);
```